# Sentry Environment showing production by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry

I am trying to config Sentry for multiple Environment but by default for all my errors Sentry showing environment as production. Below is my config, I am trying to set environment as "local"

```
{
    environment: "local",
    dsn: "{DSN Value}",

    // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    // of transactions for performance monitoring.
    // We recommend adjusting this value in production
    tracesSampleRate: sentryEnv == 'production' ? 0.2 : 0,
    integrations: [
        new Sentry.Integrations.Breadcrumbs({
            console: false
        })
    ],
    enabled: sentryEnv == 'production' ? true : false
}
```

Comment: Do you also set the `environment` variable to `local` in production?